# Would like to delete certificates

Tags: macos, certificate

How can I delete certificates on my MacBook? In the All Items category I am having to spend to much time looking for the most current certificates.

Comment: I am *assuming* you mean "SSL Certificates" but we don't like to proceed under assumptions.  Which certificates are you looking to remove exactly.  Also, this sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Certificates category instead of All Items
2. Sort on Expiry Date
3. The top one is probably the newest and you could delete the other certificates you want to delete.

[image: Activity Monitor]